# Synchronise multiple scroll div with inertia effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple `div` which scroll at the same time. I had a `css` property to have the inertia effect on my all `div` (for safari on iPad) `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. It works perfectly on the desktop web browser. But I have an effect that I want to change when i launch my webpage on my iPad.

The problem on ipad is : When i use the inertia effect, all div synchronize when the inertia effect is finished. I would like to have the same effect than the desktop web browser, that is, they are synchronized for the effect of inertia and not at the end.

You know, if there is a solution?

To complete my explanation, I created a : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVaEq/6/)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, CSS scrolling inertia on mobile devices cannot be handled with JavaScript. Element scroll event is fired when you scroll it by hand and when animation is finished. During animation no events are fired. So you have to emulate inertia with javascript to sync your divs (and this is not good idea).

Comment: So I have no solution?

Comment: You can emulate inertia effect with javascript, but it won't work as good as native scrolling inertia.